# How to generate a Java class which implements Serializable interface from xsd using JAXB?

Tags: java, xsd, jaxb, xjc

I would like to introduce caching into an existing Spring project which uses JAXB to expose WebServices. Caching will be done on the level of end points. In order to do that classes generated from XSD using JAXB need to implement `Serializable` interface and override `Object`'s `toString()` method.

How to instruct the xjc tool using XSD to generate source with needed properties?

Comment: One of possibilities is to use JAXB plugins (https://jaxb2-commons.dev.java.net/)

Comment: @dma_k and how exactly is this done with jaxb2-commons?

Answer (score 80, accepted):

### Serializable

Use `xjc:serializable` in a custom bindings file to add the `java.io.Serializable` interface to your classes along with a `serialVersionUID`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<bindings xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2000/10/XMLSchema-instance"
            xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc"
            xsi:schemaLocation="
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/bindingschema_2_0.xsd"
version="2.1">
  <globalBindings>
    <serializable uid="1" />
  </globalBindings>
</bindings>
```

### toString()

Use a superclass (see `xjc:superClass`) from which all your bound classes will inherit. This class won’t be generated by xjc so you are free to create it as you please (here with a `toString()` implementation):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<bindings xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
                xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2000/10/XMLSchema-instance"
                xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc"
                xsi:schemaLocation="
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/bindingschema_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.1">
    <globalBindings>
        <serializable uid="1" />
        <xjc:superClass name="the.package.to.my.XmlSuperClass" />
    </globalBindings>
</bindings>
```

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. Would you use apache commons lang ToStringBuilder's toString builder based on reflection?

Comment: Yes, it's a good choice in your case (actually, I don't think you have many other options).

Comment: Actually, there is: Pojomatic (http://pojomatic.sourceforge.net/pojomatic/index.html)

Comment: @Pascal: I believe, in the example one need to say `<xjc:serializable ...>`, as the default namespace is different from `xjc`.

Comment: After applying `<xjc:superClass...>` I've got `@XmlValue is not allowed on a class that derives another class`. The solution is: add `@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlTransient` annotation to base class (see here: http://sites.google.com/site/codingkb/java-2/jaxb/jaxb-4)

Comment: Is there a way to tell xjc that only some of the classes extend XMLSuperClass?

Comment: For more information about how to use a bindings file in maven, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/903629/496166.

Comment: I had to put the answer in a bindings.xml file and add `jaxb:` in front of the tags (e.g: `jaxb:bindings`) and `xjc:serializable`

and ran this in the console: `xjc -extension -d out -b bindings.xml yourSchema.xsd`

Comment: You don't need `extensionBindingPrefixes="xjc"`?

Answer (score 10):

This worked for me:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jaxb:bindings xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc" jaxb:version="2.1">
    <jaxb:globalBindings>
        <xjc:serializable uid="1337"/>
    </jaxb:globalBindings>
</jaxb:bindings>
```

Answer (score 5):

Another way to generate `toString()` method - [JAXB2 Basics Plugins](http://confluence.highsource.org/display/J2B/JAXB2+Basics+Plugins). This way looks better because doesn't use reflection. Example how to do it with maven below.

```xml
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.8.2</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generate</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <schemaDirectory>
                    ${project.basedir}/src/main/resources
                </schemaDirectory>
                <generateDirectory>
                    ${project.basedir}/src/main/java
                </generateDirectory>
                <extension>true</extension>
                <args>
                    <arg>-XtoString</arg>
                </args>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jaxb2-basics</artifactId>
                        <version>0.6.4</version>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb2-basics-runtime</artifactId>
        <version>0.6.4</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

As the result you'll get such code.

```java
public String toString() {
    final ToStringStrategy strategy = JAXBToStringStrategy.INSTANCE;
    final StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();
    append(null, buffer, strategy);
    return buffer.toString();
}

public StringBuilder append(ObjectLocator locator, StringBuilder buffer, ToStringStrategy strategy) {
    strategy.appendStart(locator, this, buffer);
    appendFields(locator, buffer, strategy);
    strategy.appendEnd(locator, this, buffer);
    return buffer;
}

public StringBuilder appendFields(ObjectLocator locator, StringBuilder buffer, ToStringStrategy strategy) {
    {
        String theName;
        theName = this.getName();
        strategy.appendField(locator, this, "name", buffer, theName);
    }
    {
        String theBank;
        theBank = this.getBank();
        strategy.appendField(locator, this, "bank", buffer, theBank);
    }
    return buffer;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

i use this code and is work for me

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jaxb:bindings xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc" jaxb:version="2.1">
    <jaxb:globalBindings>
        <xjc:serializable uid="1"/><!--If you Forgot this line your class did not be serializable--!>
    </jaxb:globalBindings>
</jaxb:bindings>
```

Answer (score 1):

in order to get interface Serializable add following binding information to the xsd-file:

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"  jaxb:version="2.0">
    <xs:annotation>
        <xs:appinfo>
            <jaxb:globalBindings optionalProperty="primitive">
                <jaxb:serializable/>
            </jaxb:globalBindings>
        </xs:appinfo>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:element name="myXsdElement">
    .....
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>`

Answer (score 1):

And here is a sample using CXF 3.1.10. Remember to include compile group: 'org.apache.cxf.xjc-utils', name: 'cxf-xjc-runtime', version: '3.1.0'

```
<jxb:bindings 
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
version="2.1">

<jxb:bindings schemaLocation="META-INF/wsdl/xsd2.xsd">

        <jxb:globalBindings xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
                <jxb:serializable uid="1"/>
              </jxb:globalBindings>
```