# How to generate classes from XSD that implements serializable?

Tags: java, eclipse, serialization, xsd, jaxb

I need to generate many classes from my XML Schema (XSD) in a package (.jar).
How can I configure these classes to be serializable?

(I'm using Eclipse and JAX-B)

Comment: Exact duplicate of [How to generate a Java class which implements Serializable interface from xsd using JAXB?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1513972/how-to-generate-a-java-class-which-implements-serializable-interface-from-xsd-usi)

Comment: @pascal: sorry, I didn't see that question before

Comment: No problem. But still, it's a dupe :)

Comment: Why? You already have XML serialization available *ipso facto.* Why do you need another mechanism?

Comment: Maybe he wants pass those classes to some function that expects some java.io.Serializable args or for some ad hoc persistance on a HttpSession.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If you are using XJC, I recomend you to read this reference: [JavaTM Architecture for XML Binding: JAXB RI Vendor Extensions Customizations](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17802_01/webservices/webservices/docs/1.6/jaxb/vendorCustomizations.html#serializable) :

You have to add in your schema aditional namespaces definition to add xjc aditional markup:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"

           xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
           xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc"
           jaxb:extensionBindingPrefixes="xjc"
           jaxb:version="1.0">
```

Then, including an `<xjc:serializable>` node within `<jaxb:globalBindings>`:

```
<xs:annotation>
   <xs:appinfo>
      <jaxb:globalBindings generateIsSetMethod="true">
          <xjc:serializable uid="12343"/>
      </jaxb:globalBindings>
   </xs:appinfo>
</xs:annotation>
```

This will cause that all the concrete classes implement the Serializable interface. Also, you can define the UUID value of the resulting classes (that's an optional attribute).

Comment: ás Tks! We found the same link :). I'll give you +1 and accept

Comment: and then to generate classes from command line. xjc -extension -d location_where_classes_to_be_generated xsd_location

Comment: Any way to make a random uid?

Comment: I am using jaxb2-maven-plugin and it throws exception when adding globalBindings : lineNumber: 17; columnNumber: 34; src-annotation: <annotation> elements can only contain <appinfo> and <documentation> elements, but 'globalBindings' was found

Comment: Tried The Above approach landed in below issue   [ERROR] compiler was unable to honor this globalBindings customization. It is attached to a wrong place, or its inconsistent with other bindings.

Answer (score 5):

I've found

```
<schema
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
  xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc"
  jaxb:extensionBindingPrefixes="xjc"
  jaxb:version="1.0"  
  >

  <!-- FORCE ALL CLASSES IMPLEMENTS SERIALIZABLE -->
  <annotation>
    <appinfo>
      <jaxb:globalBindings generateIsSetMethod="true">
        <xjc:serializable uid="1"/>
      </jaxb:globalBindings>
    </appinfo>
  </annotation>

   ....

</schema>
```