# JAXB - Serializable

Tags: java, serialization, jaxb

I am just wondering...
Is it possible to serialize (implement `Serializable` interface) for [such kind of jaxb root object](http://sushantworld.wordpress.com/2011/02/07/jaxb-custom-xml-to-java-map-using-xmladapter/) to make it possible read/write it with `ObjectOutputStream` and `ObjectInputStream`?

Or what is the optimal walkaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JAXB (JSR-222) objects are just POJOs so you can add `implements Serializable` to them. You can also JAXB to generate a Java model from an XML schema that implements Serializable.

- [How to generate classes from XSD that implements serializable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3677088/how-to-generate-classes-from-xsd-that-implements-serializable)

Comment: I am not pretty sure about XmlAdapter ? Is it serializable?