# How to generate classes using maven jaxb implements serializable

Tags: java, xsd, jaxb

I want my all xjc generated classes implementing serializable interface.
After reading solution at [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3677088/how-to-generate-classes-from-xsd-that-implements-serializable) I implemented it but `jaxb2-maven-plugin` throws below error:

> [ERROR] file: mapping.xsd [17,34]  org.xml.sax.SAXParseException;
>   systemId: file:mapping.xsd; lineNumber: 17; columnNumber: 34;
>   src-annotation:  elements can only contain  and
>    elements, but 'globalBindings' was found.     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:203)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:134)
>     at

My xsd sample:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
           xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc"
           jaxb:extensionBindingPrefixes="xjc"
           attributeFormDefault="unqualified"
           elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <xs:element name="MappingFile" type="MappingFileType">
        <xs:annotation>
            <jaxb:globalBindings>
                <xjc:serializable uid="43538530765l"/>
            </jaxb:globalBindings>
        </xs:annotation>
```

Maven plugin:

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <sources>
                        <source>xxxx/yyy/mapping.xsd</source>
                    </sources>
                    <packageName>xx.yy.zz.jaxp</packageName>

                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

Is there any dependency that i need to use to avoid this exception? Please sugest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your binding file should look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<jaxb:bindings
        xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
        xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc"
        xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/bindingschema_2_0.xsd"
        version="2.1">

    <jaxb:globalBindings>
        <xjc:serializable uid="1" />
    </jaxb:globalBindings>
</jaxb:bindings>
```

Moreover, touch your binding file in a specific directory and reference it in the maven plugin specific configuration.
Example:

```
<configuration>
    <sources>
      <source>src/main/xjb/xsd</source>
    </sources>
  <packageName>xx.yy.zz.jaxp</packageName>
    <xjbSources>
        <xjbSource>src/main/xjb/jaxb-bindings.xjb</xjbSource>
    </xjbSources>
</configuration>
```