# How can I store not serialized (JAXB) object in DB like blob?

Tags: java, serialization, blob

I have JAXB autogenerated object:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
    "chargesPackage"
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "ImportChargesRequest")
public class ImportChargesRequest
    extends RequestType
{
...
public class RequestType {

    @XmlAttribute(name = "Id", required = true)
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(CollapsedStringAdapter.class)
    @XmlID
    protected String id;
...
```

and I need save this object like BLOB in Database. But when class generated from XSD - was generated class without `serialized` and I can not serialize it/ I get exception - `java.io.NotSerializableException`

How can I store raw request in db in this case?

Answer (score 0):

You can use XJC to implement additional Serializable interface as shown here: [how-to-generate-classes-from-xsd-that-implements-serializable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3677088/how-to-generate-classes-from-xsd-that-implements-serializable).
Other option would be to serialize Your object to XML using JAXB and storing it in a BLOB column.