# JAXB generated classes serializable with JAX-WS binding

Tags: java, jaxb, jax-ws, cxf

Having JAXB-RI and CXF. WSDL first. I want a generated class of mine to implement `Serializable`. I now have the following binding xml, which works (the SEI class name gets changed)

```
<jaxws:bindings xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" ...>
    <bindings node="wsdl:definitions/wsdl:portType[@name='Foo']">
        <!-- change the generated SEI class -->
        <class name="IFooService" />
    </bindings>
</jaxws:bindings>
```

No, in this context, where and what should I add. I tried:

```
<xsd:annotation>
    <xsd:appinfo>
        <jaxb:globalBindings>
            <xjc:serializable uid="12343" />
        </jaxb:globalBindings>
    </xsd:appinfo>
</xsd:annotation>
```

and

```
<jxb:globalBindings>
    <jxb:serializable/>
</jxb:globalBindings>
```

both inside and outside the `<bindings>` tag - either `Serializable` is not added, or classes are not generated at all (without any error).

See also [this thread](http://cxf.547215.n5.nabble.com/How-to-make-classes-created-from-wsdl2java-implements-serializable-td554354.html)

So, how exactly to do that

Comment: JAXB binding customizations are a real pain in the neck. They're a hangover from the bad old days of JAXB 1.x, and it was never properly re-engineered for 2.x.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to generate a Java class which implements Serializable interface from xsd using JAXB?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1513972/how-to-generate-a-java-class-which-implements-serializable-interface-from-xsd-usi)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I made it work in two ways:

1. Using a second binding file, which is JAXB-only, as the one Pascal showed in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1513972/how-to-generate-a-java-class-which-implements-serializable-interface-from-xsd-usi/1514030#1514030)
2. By specifying another `<bindings>` tag that handles the whole namespace:

   ```
   <bindings
       node="wsdl:definitions/wsdl:types/xsd:schema[@targetNamespace='http://www.yoursite.com/services/mynamespace']">
       <jxb:globalBindings xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
           xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
           <jxb:serializable />
       </jxb:globalBindings>
   </bindings>
   ```

Comment: Can you expand on these? For #1 how do you pass the second file to `wsimport`? For #2 where in the `<jaxws:bindings>` does this go and is `jaxws` the default namespace in your example?

Answer (score 1):

You can implement an XJC plugin to do that:

```
public class SerializablePlugin extends Plugin
{

  @Override
  public boolean run(Outline outline, Options options, ErrorHandler errorHandler) throws SAXException
  {
   for (ClassOutline classOutline : outline.getClasses())
   {
    JDefinedClass definedClass = classOutline.implClass;
    definedClass._implements(codeModel.ref(Serializable.class));
   }
   return true;
  }

 ...
}
```

Then, you can add the plugin to the SchemaCompiler options:

```
WsimportOptions wsimportOptions = new WsimportOptions();
wsimportOptions.getSchemaCompiler().getOptions().activePlugins.add(new SerializablePlugin());
```