# How can I force CXF to serialize all auto generated client classes?

Tags: java, serialization, cxf

How can I force CXF to serialize all auto generated client classes? Any parameters I need to pass when runing the client generator?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What XML Binding are you using? If you are using JAXB, you'll need to have a binding file like this:

[How to generate a Java class which implements Serializable interface from xsd using JAXB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1513972/how-to-generate-a-java-class-which-implements-serializable-interface-from-xsd-usi)

When you use maven to generate your client stubs, you can add the binding file like this:

http://cxf.apache.org/docs/maven-cxf-codegen-plugin-wsdl-to-java.html

Best regards,
Alexander.