# Generating unique serializable id for each of the generated classes in JAXB

Tags: java, serialization, jaxb, xjc, wsimport

I am using ant wsimport to generate client stub from the wsdls. Also, I would like to generate client classes that implements `Serializable`. I would like to generate a different `serialVersionUID` for each class. I tried with the binding file that was shown below. But its generating same `serialVersionUID` for all the classes. Is there any way I can give my own `serialVersionUID` to each class?

```
<wsimport xendorsed="true" binding="binding.xml" debug="true" keep="true" 
verbose="false"  sourcedestdir="${generated}" wsdl="${src}${wsdl.file}"
wsdlLocation="${wsdl.file}">
</wsimport>
```

binding configuration

```
<bindings xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" version="2.0" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <globalBindings>   
        <serializable uid="1" />        
    </globalBindings>    
</bindings>
```

Comment: Waitaminute... If you implement `Serializable` you are binding yourself for a contract for life; generating _random_ UUIDs?

Comment: @fge The OP does not say he wants random `uid`s, the OP wants different `uid`s for different classes (i.e. not always the same/`1`). Theoretically it is possible to generate a `uid` based on the contents of the class. Different contents - different `uid`s. So the question makes sense to me.

Comment: `<xjc:serializable uid="1"/>` customization can only occur within your `<jaxb:globalBindings>` [see here](https://jaxb.java.net/jaxb20-ea/docs/vendorCustomizations.html). Anyway you can add a work around using binding for each element generated.

Comment: why do they need to be unique?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to generate a Java class which implements Serializable interface from xsd using JAXB?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1513972/how-to-generate-a-java-class-which-implements-serializable-interface-from-xsd-us)

Answer (score 3):

Just for the record, there is no way to generate a unique `serialVersionUID` for each generated class because **it doesn't make sense to do so**.

Let me explain : 
A `serialVersionUID` represents a version of your class at a particular point in time. If you modify your class, your `serialVersionUID` should change. 
So when the JDK deserialize objects of the same class, it knows to which version of your class to deserialize it to.

In the case of JAXB, since you generate all your classes at once every time it doesn't make sense to version all the classes individually. Simply because they can only change as a group. (Unless you take them out of your target folder..)

I hope that makes a little bit more sense.

Answer (score 2):

This is the binding file we use, which does the trick for us.

```
<xs:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" version="1.0"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc" jaxb:version="2.0"
jaxb:extensionBindingPrefixes="xjc">
<xs:annotation>
    <xs:appinfo>
        <jaxb:globalBindings>
            <xjc:serializable />
        </jaxb:globalBindings>
    </xs:appinfo>
</xs:annotation>
```

Comment: No, it’s not a complete schema, but the relevant bit to insert into your schema. At least, it did the trick to insert these lines into my WSDL file.