# maven generated jaxb classes - ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, maven, jaxb

I have a maven model project, where I am generating jaxb class by maven command - clean install
and the jaxb classes are generated under target folder and jar file is generating under .m2 repository folder.

Now on my other project adding this jar as a dependency with proper group id and artifactId.

But I am getting ClassNotFoundException and compile error for those generated jaxb classes.

I am updating my question to add more details.

The Pom File of Model Project.

```
<build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.5.1</version>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.8.3</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>spf-ssp-generate</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <generateDirectory>${project.build.directory}/jaxbclasses/pqr/xyz</generateDirectory>
                            <generatePackage>abc.vo.apply.v1</generatePackage>
                            <schemaIncludes>
                                <include>MyXSD.xsd</include>
                            </schemaIncludes>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <schemaDirectory>src/main/resources</schemaDirectory>
                    <extension>true</extension>
                    <args>
                        <arg>-XtoString</arg>
                        <arg>-Xequals</arg>
                        <arg>-XhashCode</arg>
                    </args>
                    <plugins>
                        <plugin>
                            <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons</groupId>
                            <artifactId>jaxb2-basics</artifactId>
                            <version>0.6.4</version>
                        </plugin>
                    </plugins>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

On `clean install` it generates the class files under.
target
  jaxbclasses
       pqr
         xyz

with the package name - abc.vo.apply.v1

I have another Two Maven project(jar), suppose as, A & B.
Now I can use the jaxb model project as a maven dependency, and it compile fine.

Now My Web project is not a Maven project - it is a Liferay based on Ant.
I manually copy the A, B and The Jaxb Model project in to lib folder.
It compile fines. but I am getting ClassNotFoundException.

Comment: Please add full stack trace? Also what changes you did in your  `pom.xml` to access the  `jar`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am adding another answer, which I think is more accurate.

In order to make your JAXB project compile, I had to add this dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons</groupId>
  <artifactId>jaxb2-basics</artifactId>
  <version>0.6.5</version>
</dependency>
```

which obviously won't be automatically part of your classpath for Liferay.

When I ran `mvn dependency:list`, I got this:

```
org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons:jaxb2-basics-tools:jar:0.6.4:compile
org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons:jaxb2-basics:jar:0.6.4:compile
commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.2:compile
commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1:compile
com.google.code.javaparser:javaparser:jar:1.0.8:compile
org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons:jaxb2-basics-runtime:jar:0.6.4:compile
commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.7.0:compile`
```

which means that you need to put these in the `lib` directory of your Liferay installation as well.

Comment: Awesome Daniel, You are amazing, it is working now after put those jars in my liferay project.

Comment: No problem, just glad I could help out. If you are satisfied with this answer, please consider marking it as 'correct'.

Comment: Hi Daniel,By using   following jaxb args                                               <arg>-XtoString</arg>
<arg>-Xequals</arg>
<arg>-XhashCode</arg> classes can implement     public class SPFSSPVO
    implements Equals, HashCode, ToString, help meI how the jaxb classes can implements Serializable interface.

Comment: That's really a separate question. 

Basically, you need something called a "bindings file" that the JAXB plugin needs to use. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1513972/how-to-generate-a-java-class-which-implements-serializable-interface-from-xsd-us) and [this](http://an-compsci.blogspot.se/2012/03/configuring-maven-to-autogenerate.html) article describe how it's done.

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely due to the fact that the `target` directory is never included in the jar file by default. Try configuring the JAXB classes to be generated under (say) `target/generated`. Then, add this to the build plugin section of the POM:

```
  <plugin>
     <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
     <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
     <version>1.9.1</version>
     <executions>
        <execution>
          <id>add-java-sources</id>
          <goals>
            <goal>add-source</goal>
          </goals>
          <configuration>
            <sources>
              <source>${project.build.directory}/generated</source>
            </sources>
          </configuration>
       </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

Comment: [tag:maven-jaxb2-plugin] adds the "generated" directory as a source directory automatically.

Comment: I agree, that's the default. But unless the OP posts the output from execution or the POM, we are stuck with making qualified guesses. Logically, **if** the plugin did indeed generate the code **and** automatically added the generated directory as a source folder, the code should be in the jar. Moreover, the OP could be using `org.codehaus.mojo:jaxb2-maven-plugin` for all we know.

   @Manu: could you please add more information to this post? We'd like to help out, but we need more context.

Comment: This is why I've posted it as a comment to your answer (which is points to the right direction) and not as a separate answer.

Comment: @Daniel and, I have updated the question, to add some more details.

Comment: I tried using your POM and sure enough, the classes are duly included in the jar-file. Are you declaring your dependencies correctly? How are you accessing the generated classes (by reflection or statically)? They were generated under under the `abc.vo.apply.v1` package, as expected. When you say "manually copy the A, B and The Jaxb Model project in to lib folder", you do mean the jar-files, right?

Comment: Hi Daniel, I am not using the jaxb classes, by Reflection. this is my import -import abc.vo.apply.v1.SPFSSPVO; Yes Daniel manually copy means - the three jar files copying to Lib folder.

Comment: Ok, does the exception actually say `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: abc.vo.apply.v1.SPFSSPVO` or is it some other class? Are there any nested exceptions?