# JAXB Generated POJOs not Implementing Serializable Interface

Tags: java, serialization, intellij-idea, xsd, pojo

I have the following XSD file that when I run XJC within Intellij, the corresponding POJOs do not implement Serializable:

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
        xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc"
        jaxb:extensionBindingPrefixes="xjc"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/bindingschema_2_0.xsd"
        version="2.1">

<xsd:annotation>
    <xsd:appinfo>
        <jaxb:globalBindings generateIsSetMethod="true">
            <xjc:serializable uid="1"/>
        </jaxb:globalBindings>
    </xsd:appinfo>
</xsd:annotation>

<xsd:element name="FormTemplateInfo">
    <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:sequence>
            <!-- <xsd:element ref="TrFormTemplate"/>-->
            <xsd:element ref="TrFormCd"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>

<!--<xsd:element name="TrFormTemplate" type="TrFormTemplate"/>-->
<xsd:element name="TrFormCd" type="TrFormCd"/>

<xsd:complexType name="TrFormCd">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="formCdSysId" type="xsd:int"/>
        <xsd:element name="formRequestedByNm" type="xsd:string" nillable="true"/>
        <xsd:element name="formUploadDt" type="xsd:dateTime" nillable="true"/>
        <xsd:element name="formPriceAmt" type="xsd:decimal" nillable="true"/>
        <xsd:element name="formCd" type="xsd:string" nillable="true"/>
        <xsd:element name="formLowLimitCnt" type="xsd:int" nillable="true"/>
        <xsd:element name="formDesc" type="xsd:string" nillable="true"/>
        <xsd:element name="stateRequiredEndrInd" type="xsd:string" nillable="true"/>
        <xsd:element name="formNumberedInd" type="xsd:string" nillable="true"/>
        <xsd:element name="nbrOfPartNbr" type="xsd:int" nillable="true"/>
        <xsd:element name="largeOrdrItemInd" type="xsd:string" nillable="true"/>
        <xsd:element name="auditRecCreateDts" type="xsd:dateTime" nillable="true"/>
        <xsd:element name="auditRecCreateApplUserId" type="xsd:string" nillable="true"/>
        <xsd:element name="formEndDt" type="xsd:dateTime" nillable="true"/>
        <xsd:element name="auditRecUpdtDts" type="xsd:dateTime" nillable="true"/>
        <xsd:element name="auditRecUpdtApplUserId" type="xsd:string" nillable="true"/>
        <xsd:element name="auditRecUpdtVerNbr" type="xsd:int" nillable="true"/>
        <xsd:element name="auditRecCreateApplId" type="xsd:string" nillable="true"/>
        <xsd:element name="auditRecUpdtApplId" type="xsd:string" nillable="true"/>
        <xsd:element name="auditRecCreateDbUserId" type="xsd:string" nillable="true"/>
        <xsd:element name="formSizeCd" type="xsd:string" nillable="true"/>
        <xsd:element name="formLayoutCd" type="xsd:string" nillable="true"/>
        <xsd:element name="auditRecUpdtDbUserId" type="xsd:string" nillable="true"/>
        <xsd:element name="formOrntCd" type="xsd:string" nillable="true"/>
        <xsd:element name="formStockCd" type="xsd:string" nillable="true"/>
        <xsd:element name="binderyNameCd" type="xsd:string" nillable="true"/>
        <xsd:element name="formFinishCd" type="xsd:string" nillable="true"/>
        <xsd:element name="unitCd" type="xsd:string" nillable="true"/>
        <xsd:element name="formBlob" type="xsd:base64Binary" nillable="true"/>
        <xsd:element name="isHardCopyInd" type="xsd:string" nillable="true"/>
        <xsd:element name="quantityPerPackNbr" type="xsd:int" nillable="true"/>
        <xsd:element name="rceFormNm" type="xsd:string" nillable="true"/>
        <xsd:element name="formTemplateId" type="xsd:int" nillable="true"/>
        <xsd:element name="prodSysId" type="xsd:int" nillable="true"/>
        <xsd:element name="formCdStateGrpNbr" type="xsd:string" nillable="true"/>
        <xsd:element name="formCgyCd" type="xsd:string" nillable="true"/>
        <xsd:element name="formTemplateSysId" type="xsd:int" nillable="true"/>
        <xsd:element name="TrFormTemplate" type="TrFormTemplate" nillable="true"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>


<xsd:complexType name="TrFormTemplate">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="formTemplateSysId" type="xsd:int"/>
        <xsd:element name="formTemplateNm" type="xsd:string" nillable="true"/>
        <xsd:element name="auditRecCreateDts" type="xsd:dateTime" nillable="true"/>
        <xsd:element name="auditRecCreateApplUserId" type="xsd:string" nillable="true"/>
        <xsd:element name="auditRecUpdtDts" type="xsd:dateTime" nillable="true"/>
        <xsd:element name="auditRecUpdtApplUserId" type="xsd:string" nillable="true"/>
        <xsd:element name="auditRecUpdtVerNbr" type="xsd:int" nillable="true"/>
        <xsd:element name="auditRecCreateApplId" type="xsd:string" nillable="true"/>
        <xsd:element name="auditRecUpdtApplId" type="xsd:string" nillable="true"/>
        <xsd:element name="auditRecCreateDbUserId" type="xsd:string" nillable="true"/>
        <xsd:element name="auditRecUpdtDbUserId" type="xsd:string" nillable="true"/>
        <xsd:element name="TrFormTemplateVersions" type="TrFormTemplateVersion" minOccurs="0"
                     maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>


<xsd:complexType name="TrFormTemplateVersion">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="templateVerSysId" type="xsd:int"/>
        <xsd:element name="formTemplateSysId" type="xsd:int"/>
        <xsd:element name="templateEffectDts" type="xsd:dateTime" nillable="true"/>
        <xsd:element name="formTemplateBlob" type="xsd:base64Binary" nillable="true"/>
        <xsd:element name="auditRecCreateDts" type="xsd:dateTime" nillable="true"/>
        <xsd:element name="auditRecCreateApplUserId" type="xsd:string" nillable="true"/>
        <xsd:element name="auditRecUpdtDts" type="xsd:dateTime" nillable="true"/>
        <xsd:element name="auditRecUpdtApplUserId" type="xsd:string" nillable="true"/>
        <xsd:element name="auditRecUpdtVerNbr" type="xsd:int" nillable="true"/>
        <xsd:element name="auditRecCreateApplId" type="xsd:string" nillable="true"/>
        <xsd:element name="auditRecUpdtApplId" type="xsd:string" nillable="true"/>
        <xsd:element name="auditRecCreateDbUserId" type="xsd:string" nillable="true"/>
        <xsd:element name="auditRecUpdtDbUserId" type="xsd:string" nillable="true"/>
        <xsd:element name="documentType" type="xsd:string" nillable="true"/>
        <xsd:element name="TrFormTemplateFields" type="TrFormTemplateField" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>


<xsd:complexType name="TrFormTemplateField">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="templateFldSysId" type="xsd:int"/>
        <xsd:element name="templateVerSysId" type="xsd:int"/>
        <xsd:element name="fieldSeqNo" type="xsd:int" nillable="true"/>
        <xsd:element name="formTemplateBlob" type="xsd:base64Binary" nillable="true"/>
        <xsd:element name="fieldKey" type="xsd:string" nillable="true"/>
        <xsd:element name="fieldNm" type="xsd:string" nillable="true"/>
        <xsd:element name="displType" type="xsd:string" nillable="true"/>
        <xsd:element name="displFormat" type="xsd:string" nillable="true"/>
        <xsd:element name="displLblWhenEmptyInd" type="xsd:string" nillable="true"/>
        <xsd:element name="activeInd" type="xsd:string" nillable="true"/>
        <xsd:element name="requiredInd" type="xsd:string" nillable="true"/>
        <xsd:element name="promptUserInd" type="xsd:string" nillable="true"/>
        <xsd:element name="auditRecCreateDts" type="xsd:dateTime" nillable="true"/>
        <xsd:element name="auditRecCreateApplUserId" type="xsd:string" nillable="true"/>
        <xsd:element name="auditRecUpdtDts" type="xsd:dateTime" nillable="true"/>
        <xsd:element name="auditRecUpdtApplUserId" type="xsd:string" nillable="true"/>
        <xsd:element name="auditRecUpdtVerNbr" type="xsd:int" nillable="true"/>
        <xsd:element name="auditRecCreateApplId" type="xsd:string" nillable="true"/>
        <xsd:element name="auditRecUpdtApplId" type="xsd:string" nillable="true"/>
        <xsd:element name="auditRecCreateDbUserId" type="xsd:string" nillable="true"/>
        <xsd:element name="auditRecUpdtDbUserId" type="xsd:string" nillable="true"/>
        <xsd:element name="editAfterRptInd" type="xsd:string" nillable="true"/>
        <xsd:element name="displValOnlyInd" type="xsd:string" nillable="true"/>
        <xsd:element name="TrFormFieldValues" type="TrFormFieldValue" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>


<xsd:complexType name="TrFormFieldValue">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="formFldValSysId" type="xsd:long"/>
        <xsd:element name="formFieldValueTxt" type="xsd:string" nillable="true"/>
        <xsd:element name="auditRecCreateDts" type="xsd:dateTime" nillable="true"/>
        <xsd:element name="auditRecCreateApplUserId" type="xsd:string" nillable="true"/>
        <xsd:element name="auditRecUpdtDts" type="xsd:dateTime" nillable="true"/>
        <xsd:element name="auditRecUpdtApplUserId" type="xsd:string" nillable="true"/>
        <xsd:element name="auditRecUpdtVerNbr" type="xsd:long" nillable="true"/>
        <xsd:element name="auditRecCreateApplId" type="xsd:string" nillable="true"/>
        <xsd:element name="auditRecUpdtApplId" type="xsd:string" nillable="true"/>
        <xsd:element name="auditRecCreateDbUserId" type="xsd:string" nillable="true"/>
        <xsd:element name="auditRecUpdtDbUserId" type="xsd:string" nillable="true"/>
        <xsd:element name="TrPolicies" type="TrPolicy" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>


<xsd:complexType name="TrPolicy">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="polSysId" type="xsd:int" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
        <xsd:element name="prodNbr" type="xsd:string" nillable="true"/>
        <xsd:element name="polNbr" type="xsd:string" nillable="true"/>
        <xsd:element name="relatedPolSysId" type="xsd:int" nillable="true"/>
        <xsd:element name="acctPeriodMonthYrDt" type="xsd:dateTime" nillable="true"/>
        <xsd:element name="validationDts" type="xsd:dateTime" nillable="true"/>
        <xsd:element name="agentCmsnAmt" type="xsd:decimal" nillable="true"/>
        <xsd:element name="agentPremAmt" type="xsd:decimal" nillable="true"/>
        <xsd:element name="agentNetToCoAmt" type="xsd:decimal" nillable="true"/>
        <xsd:element name="ourPremAmt" type="xsd:decimal" nillable="true"/>
        <xsd:element name="ourCmsnAmt" type="xsd:decimal" nillable="true"/>
        <xsd:element name="ourNetToCoAmt" type="xsd:decimal" nillable="true"/>
        <xsd:element name="liabAmt" type="xsd:decimal" nillable="true"/>
        <xsd:element name="polEffectDt" type="xsd:dateTime" nillable="true"/>
        <xsd:element name="enteredIntoSysDts" type="xsd:dateTime" nillable="true"/>
        <xsd:element name="polDataSourceCd" type="xsd:string" nillable="true"/>
        <xsd:element name="polSubStatCd" type="xsd:string" nillable="true"/>
        <xsd:element name="externalShipmentNbr" type="xsd:string" nillable="true"/>
        <xsd:element name="auditRecCreateDts" type="xsd:dateTime" nillable="true"/>
        <xsd:element name="auditRecCreateApplUserId" type="xsd:string" nillable="true"/>
        <xsd:element name="auditRecUpdtDts" type="xsd:dateTime" nillable="true"/>
        <xsd:element name="auditRecUpdtApplUserId" type="xsd:string" nillable="true"/>
        <xsd:element name="auditRecUpdtVerNbr" type="xsd:int" nillable="true"/>
        <xsd:element name="ratePolicyCd" type="xsd:string" nillable="true"/>
        <xsd:element name="auditRecCreateApplId" type="xsd:string" nillable="true"/>
        <xsd:element name="auditRecUpdtApplId" type="xsd:string" nillable="true"/>
        <xsd:element name="auditRecCreateDbUserId" type="xsd:string" nillable="true"/>
        <xsd:element name="auditRecUpdtDbUserId" type="xsd:string" nillable="true"/>
        <xsd:element name="relatedPolNbr" type="xsd:string" nillable="true"/>
        <xsd:element name="reissueLiabAmt" type="xsd:decimal" nillable="true"/>
        <xsd:element name="ubeOverrideInd" type="xsd:string" nillable="true"/>
        <xsd:element name="ctiBatchNbr" type="xsd:string" nillable="true"/>
        <xsd:element name="rateCalcInd" type="xsd:string" nillable="true"/>
        <xsd:element name="unitsNbr" type="xsd:int" nillable="true"/>
        <xsd:element name="unitTotalNbr" type="xsd:int" nillable="true"/>
        <xsd:element name="totalOfAllLoansAmt" type="xsd:decimal" nillable="true"/>
        <xsd:element name="uploadCmsnSplitType" type="xsd:string" nillable="true"/>
        <xsd:element name="uploadCmsnSplitAmt" type="xsd:decimal" nillable="true"/>
        <xsd:element name="rateCalcErrorCd" type="xsd:string" nillable="true"/>
        <xsd:element name="cmsnCalcErrorCd" type="xsd:string" nillable="true"/>
        <xsd:element name="correctedInd" type="xsd:string" nillable="true"/>
        <xsd:element name="migBalOffsetAmt" type="xsd:decimal" nillable="true"/>
        <xsd:element name="isMigInd" type="xsd:string" nillable="true"/>
        <xsd:element name="cmsnSplitType" type="xsd:string" nillable="true"/>
        <xsd:element name="origValidationDts" type="xsd:dateTime" nillable="true"/>
        <xsd:element name="uploadAcctPeriodMonthYrDt" type="xsd:dateTime" nillable="true"/>
        <xsd:element name="uploadSysId" type="xsd:int" nillable="true"/>
        <xsd:element name="polChckNbr" type="xsd:string" nillable="true"/>
        <xsd:element name="polChckAmt" type="xsd:decimal" nillable="true"/>
        <xsd:element name="manualMigrInd" type="xsd:string" nillable="true"/>
        <xsd:element name="autoReportLevel" type="xsd:string" nillable="true"/>
        <xsd:element name="externalMsgUpdtDts" type="xsd:dateTime" nillable="true"/>
        <xsd:element name="externalPolSysId" type="xsd:int" nillable="true"/>
        <xsd:element name="priorPolicyDts" type="xsd:dateTime" nillable="true"/>
        <xsd:element name="priorPolicyPremAmt" type="xsd:decimal" nillable="true"/>
        <xsd:element name="simultaneousAmt" type="xsd:decimal" nillable="true"/>
        <xsd:element name="chckRcptInd" type="xsd:string" nillable="true"/>
        <xsd:element name="reportedDts" type="xsd:dateTime" nillable="true"/>
        <xsd:element name="impChckAutoRptInd" type="xsd:string" nillable="true"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>


<xsd:complexType name="TrProduct">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="prodSysId" type="xsd:int"/>
        <xsd:element name="prodNbr" type="xsd:string" nillable="true"/>
        <xsd:element name="prodDesc" type="xsd:string" nillable="true"/>
        <xsd:element name="auditRecCreateDts" type="xsd:dateTime" nillable="true"/>
        <xsd:element name="auditRecCreateApplUserId" type="xsd:string" nillable="true"/>
        <xsd:element name="auditRecCreateDbUserId" type="xsd:string" nillable="true"/>
        <xsd:element name="auditRecCreateApplId" type="xsd:string" nillable="true"/>
        <xsd:element name="auditRecUpdtDts" type="xsd:dateTime" nillable="true"/>
        <xsd:element name="auditRecUpdtApplUserId" type="xsd:string" nillable="true"/>
        <xsd:element name="auditRecUpdtDbUserId" type="xsd:string" nillable="true"/>
        <xsd:element name="auditRecUpdtApplId" type="xsd:string" nillable="true"/>
        <xsd:element name="auditRecUpdtVerNbr" type="xsd:int" nillable="true"/>
        <xsd:element name="TrFormCd" type="TrFormCd" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>


<xsd:complexType name="TrFormUw">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="uwSysId" type="xsd:int"/>
        <!-- <xsd:element name="formCdSysIds" type="xsd:int" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>-->
        <xsd:element name="auditRecCreateDts" type="xsd:dateTime" nillable="true"/>
        <xsd:element name="auditRecCreateApplUserId" type="xsd:string" nillable="true"/>
        <xsd:element name="auditRecCreateDbUserId" type="xsd:string" nillable="true"/>
        <xsd:element name="auditRecCreateApplId" type="xsd:string" nillable="true"/>
        <xsd:element name="auditRecUpdtDts" type="xsd:dateTime" nillable="true"/>
        <xsd:element name="auditRecUpdtApplUserId" type="xsd:string" nillable="true"/>
        <xsd:element name="auditRecUpdtDbUserId" type="xsd:string" nillable="true"/>
        <xsd:element name="auditRecUpdtApplId" type="xsd:string" nillable="true"/>
        <xsd:element name="auditRecUpdtVerNbr" type="xsd:int" nillable="true"/>
        <xsd:element name="TrFormCd" type="TrFormCd" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        <xsd:element name="TrUnderwriters" type="TrUnderwriter" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>


<xsd:complexType name="TrUnderwriter">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="uwSysId" type="xsd:int"/>
        <xsd:element name="busNm" type="xsd:string" nillable="true"/>
        <xsd:element name="uwGlBankValidInd" type="xsd:string" nillable="true"/>
        <xsd:element name="uwAbbvCd" type="xsd:string" nillable="true"/>
        <xsd:element name="uwNbr" type="xsd:string" nillable="true"/>
        <xsd:element name="auditRecCreateDts" type="xsd:dateTime" nillable="true"/>
        <xsd:element name="auditRecCreateApplUserId" type="xsd:string" nillable="true"/>
        <xsd:element name="auditRecUpdtVerNbr" type="xsd:int" nillable="true"/>
        <xsd:element name="auditRecCreateApplId" type="xsd:string" nillable="true"/>
        <xsd:element name="auditRecUpdtApplId" type="xsd:string" nillable="true"/>
        <xsd:element name="auditRecCreateDbUserId" type="xsd:string" nillable="true"/>
        <xsd:element name="auditRecUpdtDbUserId" type="xsd:string" nillable="true"/>
        <xsd:element name="uwRceCd" type="xsd:string" nillable="true"/>
        <xsd:element name="uwLogoBlob" type="xsd:base64Binary" nillable="true"/>
        <xsd:element name="rollupUwSysId" type="xsd:int" nillable="true"/>
        <xsd:element name="altBusNm" type="xsd:string" nillable="true"/>
        <xsd:element name="consolidatedRceCd" type="xsd:string" nillable="true"/>
        <xsd:element name="consolidatedDt" type="xsd:dateTime" nillable="true"/>
        <xsd:element name="TrFormUws" type="TrFormUw" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        <xsd:element name="TrUnderwriterImages" type="TrUnderwriterImage" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>

<xsd:complexType name="TrUnderwriterImage">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="uwSysId" type="xsd:int"/>
        <xsd:element name="imageTypeCd" type="xsd:string" nillable="true"/>
        <xsd:element name="imageBlob" type="xsd:base64Binary" nillable="true"/>
        <xsd:element name="auditRecCreateDts" type="xsd:dateTime" nillable="true"/>
        <xsd:element name="auditRecUpdtApplUserId" type="xsd:string" nillable="true"/>
        <xsd:element name="auditRecUpdtVerNbr" type="xsd:int" nillable="true"/>
        <xsd:element name="auditRecCreateApplId" type="xsd:string" nillable="true"/>
        <xsd:element name="auditRecUpdtApplId" type="xsd:string" nillable="true"/>
        <xsd:element name="auditRecCreateDbUserId" type="xsd:string" nillable="true"/>
        <xsd:element name="auditRecUpdtDbUserId" type="xsd:string" nillable="true"/>
        <xsd:element name="imageFileNm" type="xsd:string" nillable="true"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>


<xsd:complexType name="TrFormState">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="formCdSysId" type="xsd:int" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        <xsd:element name="formStateStatCd" type="xsd:string" nillable="true"/>
        <xsd:element name="effectDt" type="xsd:dateTime" nillable="true"/>
        <xsd:element name="auditRecCreateDts" type="xsd:dateTime" nillable="true"/>
        <xsd:element name="priorStatCd" type="xsd:string" nillable="true"/>
        <xsd:element name="auditRecCreateApplUserId" type="xsd:string" nillable="true"/>
        <xsd:element name="auditRecCreateDbUserId" type="xsd:string" nillable="true"/>
        <xsd:element name="auditRecCreateApplId" type="xsd:string" nillable="true"/>
        <xsd:element name="auditRecUpdtDts" type="xsd:dateTime" nillable="true"/>
        <xsd:element name="auditRecUpdtApplUserId" type="xsd:string" nillable="true"/>
        <xsd:element name="auditRecUpdtDbUserId" type="xsd:string" nillable="true"/>
        <xsd:element name="auditRecUpdtVerNbr" type="xsd:int" nillable="true"/>
        <xsd:element name="stateCd" type="xsd:string" nillable="true"/>
        <xsd:element name="fileNoteTxt" type="xsd:string" nillable="true"/>
        <xsd:element name="fileDt" type="xsd:dateTime" nillable="true"/>
        <xsd:element name="atFormApprInd" type="xsd:string" nillable="true"/>
        <xsd:element name="rceFormCd" type="xsd:string" nillable="true"/>
        <xsd:element name="atRestrictedInd" type="xsd:string" nillable="true"/>
        <xsd:element name="arFormApprInd" type="xsd:string" nillable="true"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
```

I've followed the instructions on the following 
[Oracle JAXB:](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/webservices/webservices/docs/1.6/jaxb/vendorCustomizations.html#serializable)

[How to generate a Java class which implements Serializable interface from xsd using JAXB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1513972/how-to-generate-a-java-class-which-implements-serializable-interface-from-xsd-us)

Please tell me what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I simply modified the XSD to have

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
```

instead of

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
        xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc"
        jaxb:extensionBindingPrefixes="xjc"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/bindingschema_2_0.xsd"
        version="2.1">
```