# xjc error with ant "customization is not associated with any schema element"

Tags: java, xml, ant, jaxb, xjc

My issue is a lot like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15230503/jaxb-the-schemabindings-customization-is-not-associated-with-any-schema-elemen) one but with a few small differences that make me completely at a loss.

I'm trying to compile some java classes using xjc with an xsd with an xjb customization to bind jaxb:Date to java date.  It worked fine when I ran it from command line but I'm trying to incorporate it into an ant script now and I"m getting an error:

[ERROR] The "jaxb:globalBindings" customization is not associated with any schema element.

here is my xjb:

```
<jaxb:bindings xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" jaxb:version="2.0"    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<jaxb:globalBindings>
      <jaxb:javaType   name="java.util.Date"
    xmlType="xs:dateTime"
    parseMethod="sel.date.XsdDateTimeConverter.unmarshal"
    printMethod="sel.date.XsdDateTimeConverter.marshalDateTime"        
      /><jaxb:javaType 
    name="java.util.Date"
    xmlType="xs:date"
    parseMethod="sel.date.XsdDateTimeConverter.unmarshal"
    printMethod="sel.date.XsdDateTimeConverter.marshalDate"
    />
</jaxb:globalBindings>
</jaxb:bindings>
```

I'm not using maven so I can't really use the answer listed above.  Also it seems like that one needs to know of the schema that's going to incorporate it but I don't really want to do that because I'm trying to make this a general script I can use for different xsd's.

anyone have any ideas on what I'm missing here?

Comment: I get the exact same error, except I'm using maven.

Comment: Are you, by any chance, using OSX and recently did an upgrade to Mavericks?

Comment: Nope, just simply eclipse on windows.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change `jaxb:version="2.0"`  to `jaxb:version="2.1"`.

Of course it depends on your jaxb generator.

Answer (score 0):

This may be due to a older version of jaxb and xjc. I encountered this error when running the maven-jaxb-plugin 1.1, upping the version of the plugin resolved the issue.