# How to resolve already defined elements in WSDL?

Tags: java, c#, web-services, jaxb, wsdl

I'm trying to connect to a C#/NET (*.svc) webservice. I have to use java, thus `wsdl2java` is my choice.

Problem: somehow the targeting webservice defines lots of elements dublicate. This might be due to the nature of C# or whatever.

There are like 100+ elements as follows:

```
<xs:complexType name="Ticket">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="ASegment"
            nillable="true" type="tns:AnArray" />
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:element name="Ticket" nillable="true" type="tns:Ticket" />
```

Resulting in:

```
'Ticket' is already defined (org.apache.cxf:cxf-codegen-plugin:3.0.1:wsdl2java:generate-sources:generate-sources)
```

How can I cope with this? I read about a `jaxb-binding.xml` file, where I can "rename" specific elements explicit.

But if I apply this for 100+ elements, well the week has only 5 days...

Is there any way I can though auto generate the classes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see this answer:

[Prefixing JAXB generated classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/892298/prefixing-jaxb-generated-classes)

[`jaxb:nameXmlTransform`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/webservices/webservices/docs/1.5/tutorial/doc/JAXBUsing4.html#wp148550) is your friend.

I normally do `<jaxb:elementName suffix="Element"/>`.

Comment: Interesting. Is it also possible to append a `suffix="Type"` on each `xs:complexType` element??

Comment: Because, if every element is appended the suffix as you described, that would not be of any help for me, as the same-named `xs:complexType` and `xs:element` occur right after each other inside the same wsdl/xsd files.

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is. If you define `elementName` with suffix then elements will be suffixed and types - not. Should be no  collissions with that. Anyway, there's also `typeName`, please do read the links I posted.